# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I am getting a "failed to instantiate module" error when trying to inject and use an Angular service that I wrote. I have an HTML page that calls an API. I need to be able to take the return value from the API and store it for use in another controller.

Here is the HTML page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="auth">
<head>
    <title>Login AngularJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="auth" ng-controller="Login">
        <form method="post" ng-submit="login()" novalidate ng-controller="Login">
            DBID<input type="text" name="dbId" value="23" ng-model="dbId" /> UserName
            <input type="text" name="username" value="test@test.com" ng-model="username" /> Password
            <input type="text" name="password" value="test1234" ng-model="password" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="login" />
            <p>The Token is: {{token}}</p>
        </form>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/app/sharedProperties.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/app/login.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller:

```js
var auth = angular.module('auth', ['SharedProperties']);

auth.controller('Login', function ($scope, $http, SharedProperties)
{
    $scope.list = [];

    $scope.login = function ()
    {
        if ($scope.dbId) {

            $scope.list.push(this.dbId);
            $scope.text = '';

            var Credentials = new Object();
            Credentials.DBID = this.dbId;
            Credentials.username = this.username;
            Credentials.password = this.password;

            $http({
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:55049/api/Security/Login',
                data: Credentials,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic VGVzdEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uVG9rZW46'
                }
            }).then(function (response)
            {
                $scope.token = response.data;
            });

        } else
        {
            alert("Please add DBID");
        }
    };
});
```

And here is my service code:

```js
var auth = angular.module('auth', []);

auth.service('SharedProperties', function ()
{
    var property = '';

    return {
        getProperty: function ()
        {
            return property;
        },
        setProperty: function (value)
        {
            property = value;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use separate module for your shared properties, you should initialise that module. Replace

```
var auth = angular.module('auth', []);
```

with

```
var auth = angular.module('SharedProperties', []);
```

in your service code.

Comment: That fixed the issue at hand but unfortunately when I retrieve the value in the other controller (after setting it in the first controller) the value is an empty string. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please mark it as accepted answer then. Re. property service, try using self=this and self.property instead of just property variable.